# Rationalize $\frac{\sqrt{t}}{\sqrt[4]{t}+\sqrt{t}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, rationalising-denominator

Rationalize
$$C=\dfrac{\sqrt{t}}{\sqrt[4]{t}+\sqrt{t}}$$

We have $D_t:t>0.$ I did the following:
$$C=\dfrac{\sqrt{t}}{\sqrt[4]{t}+\sqrt[4]{t^2}}\cdot\dfrac{\sqrt[4]{t}-\sqrt[4]{t^2}}{\sqrt[4]{t}-\sqrt[4]{t^2}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{t}\left(\sqrt[4]{t}-\sqrt{t}\right)}{\sqrt{t}-t}\cdot\dfrac{\sqrt{t}+t}{\sqrt{t}+t}=\\=\dfrac{\sqrt{t}(\sqrt[4]{t}-\sqrt{t})(\sqrt{t}+t)}{t-t^2},t\ne1.$$

When $t=1$
$$C=\dfrac{1}{1+1}=\dfrac{1}{2}$$

The given answer in my book is $$C=\dfrac{(\sqrt[4]{t}-\sqrt{t})(1+\sqrt{t})}{1-t}.$$ Where am I wrong, or how can I further simplify my answer? Is this a reasonable approach? Thank you!

Comment: Just factor out a $\sqrt{t}$  from $(\sqrt{t}+t)$ in your last expression and together with the $\sqrt{t}$ in front, cancel a $t$ in the denominator.

Comment: Your answer matches the given answer.

Answer (score 1):

You did really quite well on this problem! All you need is one last step:

\begin{align}
    \dfrac{\color{#c00}{\sqrt{t}}(\sqrt[4]{t} - \sqrt{t})\color{#c00}{(\sqrt{t} + t)}}{t - t^2} &= 
    \dfrac{(\color{#c00}{\sqrt{t}\cdot\sqrt{t}})(\sqrt[4]{t} - \sqrt{t})\color{#c00}{(1 + \sqrt{t})}}{\color{#c00}{t}(1 - t)}\\
    &= \dfrac{\color{#c00}{t}(\sqrt[4]{t} - \sqrt{t})(1 + \sqrt{t})}{\color{#c00}{t}(1 - t)}\\
    &= \dfrac{(\sqrt[4]{t} - \sqrt{t})(1 + \sqrt{t})}{1 - t}
\end{align}
and you have the exact answer you are looking for!